# Receive value from checkbox JAVA

Tags: java, checkbox

I have 2 checkbox Male and Female. I want when I click to Male checkbox and press button Add, the row of Table will get value "Male", I use addItemListener to checkbox but I have to press 2 times then the value appear. So can anyone know how to do that easier. Thank you !

```
public void Add () throws SQLException
{   

    String MNV = TX1.getText();
    String HNV = TX2.getText();
    String TNV = TX3.getText();
    String GT1 = Nam.getText();
    String GT2 = Nu.getText();
    String NS = TX5.getText();
    String TD = TX6.getText();
    String SDT = TX7.getText();
    String DC = TX8.getText();
    Statement s = connect.createStatement();
    Nam.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent E)
        {          
            try {                    
                s.execute("INSERT INTO `nhanvien` "
                        + "(`MÃ NV`, `HỌ NV`, `TÊN NV`, `GIỚI TÍNH`, `NĂM SINH`, `TRÌNH ĐỘ`, `SỐ ĐT`, `ĐỊA CHỈ`)"      
                        + " VALUES ('"+MNV+"', '"+HNV+"', '"+TNV+"',   '"+GT1+"', '"+NS+"', '"+TD+"', '"+SDT+"', '"+DC+"');");
                GetData();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Assuming you want to only process the data in the "add" method, you don't need a listener on the checkbox, simply check it's "selected" state (which will depend on the framework you are using)

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with upper case characters.